# Solving normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Please help me.. how to solve this question with normal distribution. I am trying to learn normal distribution. however, I have difficulties.

The average grade for a course is 61 and standard deviation is 12. Suppose that grades follow a normal distribution. If 5% of class is given A’s, what is the lowest possible integer value grade to get an A?

Comment: @Thanassis after this question a little bit I messed up. I know only how to calculate pdf of it .

Answer (score 0):

Just check the value $x$ for $p(X>=x)=95\%$ where $x$ follows $N(61,12^2)$. Then the minimum grade will be $x$.

Comment: what do mean p(X>=x)=95% ? u mean our x= 95 ?

Comment: No, duanduan means, look up the $Z$ table for the $\alpha$ value that corresponds to a tail of $0.9500$, then transform that from $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1^2)$ to $X\sim\mathcal N(61, 12^2)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp 0.82894 = (x-61)/12  am I correct?